# An X509 certificate with easyrsa with CN only (no SAN)

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I'm trying to create a certificate with the hostname in the CN, without using a SAN.
I know it is a deprecated, but I'm still interested in doing so for an old legacy project.

1. `./easyrsa init-pki`
2. `./easyrsa build-ca // choose CA and passcode`
3. `./easyrsa build-server-full *.someorg.com nopass`

It used to create a signed certificate with the Subject as the hostname in the CN with a wildcard on the prefix of the domain.
But it is also adding the CN to the SAN.

Is there are way to disable the addition of the SAN inclusion?

Thanks,
Roi.

Comment: IIRC easyrsa is a front end to abstract some  of the more fiddly openssl commands. If using easyrsa doesn’t quite fit your needs you may still need to resort to using those fiddly openssl commands to create the exact certificate signing request and signed cert that fits your requirements

Comment: You are right, easyrsa is a wrapper over openssl. but I prefer to use higher level applications to create certificates and not go as low level as openssl.